# Angularjs 1.5.x localization best practices

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[Here](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide)

> For newer versions of the framework (>=1.4.0) use the built-in i18n
>   tools, when using older versions (<1.4.0) use angular-translate.

[In documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) there are many steps for localization

I found

a) [angular-localize](https://github.com/blueimp/angular-localize)

b) [angular-localization](https://github.com/doshprompt/angular-localization)

But they have little stars.

What best practices for localization there are?

I think easy way is

1. Use attribute "lcz" in html

index.html

```html
<div lcz>Hi <span>{model.Name}</span></div>
<div lcz>Hello <span>{model.Name}</span></div>
```

2. With gulp parse all htmls and generate localization resources (merge with previous generated)

```
{
  "global": 
  {
   "Hi ": 
   {
    "en": "Global Hi en ",
    "ru": "Global Hi ru ",
   }
   "Hello ":
   {
    "en": "Global Hello en ",
    "ru": "Global Hello ru ",
   }
  }
  "index.html":
  {
   {
    "en": "Local Hi en ",
    "ru": "Local Hi ru ",
   }
   "Hello ":
   {
    "en": "",
    "ru": "",
   }
  }
}
```

3. Run build localized htmls
   *index.html > index.en.html* and *index.html > index.ru.html*
   where text will be replaced with localized resource

first div use "Local Hi en "

second div use "Global Hello en "

There is a similar library?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, by localization if you mean language translation. In that case your best bet is [`angular-translate`](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

You can specify the languages in your applications configuration, or load them as `.json`.

To specify the content that needs to be translated, add a  `| translate` filter like

```
<h2>{{ 'hello' | translate }}</h2>
```

or using the  `translate` directive:

```
<h2 translate="hello"></h2>
```

Well, it is much deeper than that, it supports stuff like dynamic language switching, and has few extensions such as localStorage, cookie for remembering users language preference and has pretty good support (*and stars*)